# Excel Solver completing without solving problem

Tags: excel, optimization, solver

I am trying to maximise a value with solver. Solver was able to minimise another value fine, but when trying to maximise a different value, solver will complete (saying it found a solution) without actually finding a solution.
I can change the input cells manually to change the value that I want to solve.
Solver seems to only be able to solve one cell on the sheet and not any others.

Comment: We really need a [mcve]. Can you please tell us what to do so that we can experience the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Reading [ask] might also help.